# Timezone mess dependend on database table

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a confusing problem. I have four different tables in a PostgreSQL database. Using Java I get some timestamps from the tables and work with these. Now the problem:
In order to show them corretly I have to change the time using timezones on two tables but not on the other two. This is done with this code example

```
Timestamp lowest = getLowestTimestampFromDB(); 
Timestamp highest= getHighestTimestampFromDB(); 

int diffHours = getDifference(lowest, highest);
Timestamp[] hours = new Timestamp[diffHours+2];
for (int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    c.setTime(timestamp);
    long gmtTime = c.getTime().getTime();
    long timezoneAlteredTime = gmtTime + TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1").getRawOffset();
    c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-1"));
    c.setTime(new Timestamp(timezoneAlteredTime));
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1*i);
    hours[i] = new Timestamp(c.getTimeInMillis());
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hours));
System.out.println(lowest);
System.out.println(highest);
```

The prints are correct for two tables

```
[1970-01-01 00:00:00.0, 1970-01-01 01:00:00.0, 1970-01-01 02:00:00.0]
1970-01-01 00:00:00.0
1970-01-01 02:00:00.0
```

And wrong for the other two

```
[1970-01-01 10:00:00.0, 1970-01-01 11:00:00.0, 1970-01-01 12:00:00.0]
1970-01-01 11:00:00.0
1970-01-01 12:00:00.0
```

All timestamps in the database are without timezone.
I just don't get why sometimes I have to subtract one hour and sometimes not.

EDIT: Code extended.

Comment: The code you have shown does not interact with the database in any way.

Comment: That's correct it just shows how I change the timestamp.

Comment: *Exactly* what are the data types of your database columns with the date-time values?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that GMT is affected by Daylight Savings Time.
Try using Universal Coordinated Time: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")`.